# Date Issue ,Working Fine in Local,but in Server it takes date min value (mvc C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquerydatetimepicker

The C# Code I have used,

```
DateTime _dtFYS = new DateTime(_lab.fys.Year, _lab.fys.Month, _lab.fys.Day, 0, 0, 1);
DateTime _dtFYE = new DateTime(_lab.fye.Year, _lab.fye.Month, _lab.fye.Day, 23, 59, 59);

cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fys", _dtFYS.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt"));

cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fye", _dtFYE.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt"));
```

So in this above code the selected date from jquery datepicker will be passed and when i debug it in local system it works fine,once i deploy it in server the problem arises as error converting datetime to nvarchar.

I tried using Logger and in that the value is passing as 01/01/0001..

Comment: Dates have *no* format, either in C# or SQL Server. They are *binary values*. The call to `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt")` is a bug. Your query should accept date-typed parameters (date, datetime, datetime2, datetimeoffset), not strings. The table fields should be date-typed as well

Comment: So Is there an alternative to convert to the required date format

Comment: BTW you haven't posted your query or how you call it.

Comment: The Table datatype is  DateTime only and values passing in sql storedprocedure (parameter )is also datetime only @Panagiotis

Comment: You don't need any alternatives. There is no format. Just add the parameters *properly* (ie no AddWithValue) and pass the date value directly, eg `.Parameters["@fys"].Value=_dtFYS;`. `AddWithValue` will *guess* the correct type and can easily get it wrong, eg pass a `datetime` value when you expected a `date`. This can cause trouble other cases, eg if it passes the wrong string size to a fixed-width char parameter

Comment: `values passing in sql storedprocedure is also datetime` Then why are you trying to feed it strings? Just leave off the entire `.ToString(...)` part

Comment: Will Try and Let you know , Thanks for your replies Panagiotis and nyerguds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problematic part is when you are trying to format the value like so : _dtFYS.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt")

Dont apply this format, just pass it as a normal string or datetime. Database will store it in binary form and then you can display the value when you retrieve it with the format you are applying to it.